# apiary.io—404—No Resource Found, does anyone know what my mistake is?

Tags: curl, documentation, apiary

I want to create specifications using apiary.io, but it seems that when I tried to test one of my codes, it didn't work.

I tried to execute the delete command using

curl -X  DELETE  http://private-624ded-ecom8.apiary-mock.com/dashboard/pages/delete/34

Here is my documentation for the delete page

### Delete Pages [/dashboard/pages/delete/pageId]

#### Delete an existing page [DELETE]

You may create your own question using this action. It takes a JSON
object containing a question and a collection of answers in the
form of choices.

- Request (application/json)

  ```
  {
      pageId: "34"
  }
  ```
- Response 201 (application/json)

  - Headers

    ```
    Location: /dashboard/pages/delete/pageId
    ```
  - Body

    ```
    {
        pageId: "34"
    }
    ```

Answer (score 0):

you need to set `pageId` as param `/dashboard/pages/delete/{pageId}`

https://apiblueprint.org/documentation/examples/07-parameters.html

Comment: Thanks a lot, your answer helps me a lot. I have solved this issue and now it is working well